# Flutter firestore compound querying not working

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i have a compound firestore query. which dosent give any data but when called single it works
this is the compound query

```
 final companyQuery = await _userCollection
          .collection("invoices")
          .where("company.id", isEqualTo: companyId)
          .where("date",
              isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: Timestamp.fromDate(dateTimeRange.start),
              isLessThanOrEqualTo: Timestamp.fromDate(dateTimeRange.end))
          .get();
```

but when i call like this it works

```
 final companyQuery = await _userCollection
          .collection("invoices")
   
          .where("date",
              isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: Timestamp.fromDate(dateTimeRange.start),
              isLessThanOrEqualTo: Timestamp.fromDate(dateTimeRange.end))
          .get();
```

also works like this too

```
inal companyQuery = await _userCollection
          .collection("invoices")
          .where("company.id", isEqualTo: companyId)
          .get();
```

my document screenshot
[image: firestore document]

company objected expanded [image]

this is the print statement

```
companyId: lJHLM9sfcwXyPXo18iCX , dateTimeRange: 2022-01-30 00:00:00.000Z - 2022-03-02 21:25:13.563
[cloud_firestore/failed-precondition] The query requires an index. You can create it here:
https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/habllen/firestore/indexes?create_composite=Ckhwcm9qZWN0cy9oYWJsbGVuL2RhdGFiYXNlcy8oZGVmYXVsdCkvY29sbGVjdGlvbkdyb3Vwcy9pbnZvaWNlcy9pbmRleGVzL18QARoOCgpjb21wYW55LmlkEAEaCAoEZGF0ZRABGgwKCF9fbmFtZV9fEAE
error: FirestoreFailure.unexpected()
```

my index is

[image]

it dosent work when it queried together.
please help me solve this issue. I have also tried adding composite index

Comment: 1) Can you edit your question to show a screenshot of a document in the Firestore console that you expect to be returned by this query? --- 2) Can you `print(companyId)` and add the updated code and its output to your question?

Comment: I have edited the question. the problem is not with that query.problem only exist when two queries are compounded

Comment: You have done neither of the things I asked in my first comment, which makes it hard to help.

Comment: sorry for late reply, i have edited as you asked.

Comment: the documentation says ''"You can chain multiple equality operators (== or array-contains) methods to create more specific queries (logical AND). However, you must create a composite index to combine equality operators with the inequality operators, <, <=, >, and !="'' i tried making composite query by ascending the field company.id and descending the field date

Comment: If you're missing a required index, the SDK will log an error saying so. This error includes a direct link to the Firebase console to create the required index, with all fields already populated. So I recommend looking for such a message if you suspect the problem may be due to a missing index.

Comment: thanks the problem is solved. before i created index manually but when i followed that link it created index and it solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

If you're missing a required index, the SDK will log an error saying so. This error includes a direct link to the Firebase console to create the required index, with all fields already populated. I recommend looking for such a message if you suspect the problem may be due to a missing index.

Answer (score 0):

I read firebase documentation and it looks like it is only possible to make compound queries on only one field. As this example from the documentation states:

```
cities_ref = db.collection("cities")
cities_ref.where("state", ">=", "CA").where("state", 
"<=","IN")
```

It won't work and even not give you an error message if you try to query with two different fields like this:

```
cities_ref = db.collection("cities")
cities_ref.where("state", ">=", "CA").where("population", 
">=", 1000000)
```

So, my suggestion to you will be, try to query the first part:

```
final companyQuery = await _userCollection
          .collection("invoices")
          .where("company.id", isEqualTo: companyId)
          .get();
```

Then, after getting your snapshots, do a conditional if-else statement on them to sort and get those you need. I hope it helps you out.

Check this reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: the documentation says it cant do range queries on different fields. but I have one equality and range filter which is valid in the documentation